# this.app.client.electron.remote.app.getApplicationMenu() returns undefined

Tags: electron, e2e-testing, spectron

I am working on setting up e2e testing for Electron app that has custom menus. I want to test these custom menus. I tried several ways to access 'getApplicationMenu()' from Spectron's Application client. But all of them return 'undefined'.

```
this.app.client.electron.remote.app.getApplicationMenu()
```